# mysql procedure parameter to where clause not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters, triggers, where-clause

Mysql procedure will ignore parameter when it is inside of WHERE CLAUSE.
MySQL Statement (tested outside of Procedure) will work.
Even when tested inside of Procedure, parameter will be see and recognized as long as it is outside of WHERE clause.

Sample code below:

```
DELIMITER ;
use db_name;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `proc_name`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_name`(IN _insertId INT)
BEGIN

-- DISPLAYED CORRECTLY HERE
SELECT _insertId INTO @insertbuff;

SELECT 
`TABLE1_ALIAS1`.`PARAM1_ALIAS`,
`TABLE2_ALIAS2`.`PARAM2_ALIAS`,
`TABLE3_ALIAS3`.`PARAM3_ALIAS`
INTO @VAR1, @VAR2, @VAR3,
FROM `TABLE1` AS `TABLE1_ALIAS1` 
INNER JOIN `TABLE2` AS `TABLE2_ALIAS2` ON ...
JOIN `TABLE3` AS `TABLE3_ALIAS3` ON ...
-- SEEMS TO BE IGNORE IN THIS WHERE CLAUSE
WHERE `MAIN_TXN`.`id` = _insertId -- OPTION 1: NOT WORKING
-- WHERE `TABLE1`.`id` = CONCAT('', @insertbuff); -- OPTION 2: ALSO NOT WORKING


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You must complete the sql joins and include the  MAIN_TXN table in query?

Comment: Hi @IvanCachicatari. Contribution is appreciated. In this case, issue was elsewhere.

Comment: FYI: **TABLE1_ALIAS1 at Line 2 is actually MAIN_TXN**. (sample code in this post was edited to give random names - same error not in original code). But fix was in where clause:I first stored _insertId into @buffInsert. then used: **WHERE `MAIN_TXN`.`id` = (SELECT @insertBuff)** in the where clause. Eliminating all tabulations from code also participated in fixing issue. Feedback is appreciated!